# How to use insert into select to insert both values from select and known values in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g, insert-into

I have 5 columns out of which I have known values for 2 columns.
I have to insert values for 3 columsn using INSERT INTO...SELECT statement and the code is working.

I only want to know how do I combine both INSERT INTO SELECT with known values in ORACLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into destination (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
select 'static_value1', 'static_value2', col6, col7, col8
from source_table
```